# Midlleware not called for ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

ASP.NET Core 3.1 project has a custom middleware which injects a route data value based on the request url domain.

```
public class IdentificationMiddleware {
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public IdentificationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this._next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) {
       var identification = ...;  
       if (!identification) {
           context.abort();
       } else {
          var routeData = context.GetRouteData();
          routeData.Values.Add("identification", identification); 
       }
       await _next(context);
    }
}
```

The middleware is registered in Startup:

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseMiddleware<IdentificationMiddleware>();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
});
```

The middleware is called as expected when the url is routed to a classic controller but it is not called at all if the url is routed to an api controller (ones with the [ApiController] attribute).

```
[Route("api/some")]
[ApiController]
public sealed class SomeApiController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("apiAction")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ApiAction(
        string identification,
        [FromQuery] long id)
    {
    }
 }
```

An attempt to call this `api/some/apiAction` url results in:

```
{
    "type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title":"One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status":400,
    "traceId":"guid",
    "errors":{
        "identification":["The identification field is required."]
    }
}
```

Why is the middleware not called before calling actions in api controllers? It's possible to have it called? How to fix it?

Comment: Don't you need `[FromRoute] string identification` in your `ApiAction()` method signature?

Comment: Thanks. That made the difference.